# Running code on attacker machine from a reverse ssh exploit? (Low level theoretical explanation required)

Tags: reverse-shell

Reverse shell. A victim server runs a malicious binary which creates an SSH connection to the attacker machine. Then the attacker machine SSH's to the victim server and runs commands (that way you bypass the firewall and closed ports). Thats fine.

Now, I heard that, as the victim server starts the ssh connection to the attacker machine, in theory, it could run commands on the attacker machine (as a normal ssh connection).

How does this reverse shell work at a low level? I mean, the victim machine opens a client-ssh, not a server-ssh. The victim binary forks into a server-ssh? It opens a new port and runs a server-ssh? Is the same tunnel reused, or there are actually 2 tunnels with two different ports? Or the protocol is bidirectional and the client-ssh can actually run commands on the origin machine? I don't get how, if a machine connects via ssh to a machine, the receiving machine could send commands to run on the machine that started the connection. Or there is a custom variation on the ssh-client on the malicious code that enables to run commands?

Comment: Why would the victim need to run a server in order to run commands on the attacker? Are you also aware that the reverse shell doesn't need to be ssh at all? It's looking like you are trying to combine too many concepts into one.

Comment: I googled https://www.google.com/search?q=what+is+a+reverse+shell and the top 3 hits provide detailed explanations include code examples.

Comment: At a low level - it's just one process on the victim's machine, and one ssh connection throughout.  The victim's machine starts an ssh client process, which connects to the attacker's ssh server, and sends a command to the server to start a reverse ssh tunnel.  Then, the attacker's server can send commands to the ssh client running on the victim's machine (still the same process on the victim's machine that connected to the attacker's server in the first step, and still using the same ssh connection), and the client on the victim's machine runs these commands.

Comment: @mti2935 thank you. The actual question is, the user from the victim machine could run commands on the attacker's machine, as the ssh connection is first made from the victim's machine? Is the attacker vulnerable itself by letting an ssh connection in?

Comment: @monstercode To prevent the user from the victim machine from running commands on the attacker's machine (where the ssh server is running), the attacker can run a restricted shell on the server (such as [rbash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Restricted-Shell.html)).  See https://serverfault.com/questions/1093243/how-to-restrict-a-user-to-rbash-when-logging-in-via-ssh for more info.

Comment: @mti2935 Thank you! very useful info!